# Create ripple effect on image click CSS

Tags: css

After reading some article I have managed to create a ripple effect when a button is clicked.

Now I want to use image as a button but when I insert `img` tag inside `button` the image is not aligned properly.

```js
$(".pulse-button").click(".pulse-button", function () {
            $(this).removeClass("clicked");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".pulse-button").addClass("clicked");
            }, 10);
        });
```

```css
button.pulse-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-color: #DF56FC;
    border: none;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.pulse-button:active {
    padding: 0 6px;
    background-color: #DF56FC;
}

.clicked {
    animation: boxShadowAnim 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes boxShadowAnim {
    from {
        box-shadow: rgba(222, 80, 252, 1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow: rgba(255, 224, 178, 0) 0px 0px 0px 80px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <button name="pulse-button" class="pulse-button">
        <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/5/098847ea1a681b68536212a29b6f062a-full.png" alt="">
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I align the image properly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

Add these properties to img.

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```js
$(".pulse-button").click(".pulse-button", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("clicked");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".pulse-button").addClass("clicked");
  }, 10);
});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.another-btn1{

  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 75%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}
.another-btn2{

  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 85%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}
button.pulse-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #DF56FC;
  border: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.pulse-button:active {
  padding: 0 6px;
  background-color: #DF56FC;
}

.clicked {
  animation: boxShadowAnim 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes boxShadowAnim {
  from {
    box-shadow: rgba(222, 80, 252, 1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 224, 178, 0) 0px 0px 0px 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <button name="pulse-button" class="pulse-button">
        <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/5/098847ea1a681b68536212a29b6f062a-full.png" alt="">
      </button>
          <button name="pulse-button" class="another-btn1">
           btn 2
      </button>
                <button name="pulse-button" class="another-btn2">
           btn 3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please help me with one more thing? How do I put 2 buttons underneath the image? Next line of the image?

Comment: I can't recommend to use this solution since `position: absolute` is not necessery at all for solving this problem. It introduces many more problems, such as the answer only working in full screen mode. But that's just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

You set the width for your button as 80px * 80px. The size of your image however is 256px * 192px.

You can resize the image by specifying

```
img {
  width: 100%
}
```

Keep in mind that your image has much whitespace around it, so the image will now be very small. I would suggest you edit the image before you use it to better fit into your desired sizes.

Comment: it's a png image so I don't think there would be any whitespace around it.

Comment: it's not `whitespace` in the sense that it is white it's just empty (transparent) space. If you open the image in an editor you see what I mean, it has ~80px of empty space from all sides.

Comment: ohh yeah, I see what you mean.